# SQLException: the result set is closed

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am a beginner in Java using NetBeans and I was trying to create something similar to a faculty registration system. I use SQL Server 2005 to create the DB.
During the implementation I was trying to create a function to make students able to register their subjects so the function basically searches for the subjects that the student has finished their prerequisites. So I wrote the following code:

```
package GUIs;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class AddSubToStd extends javax.swing.JFrame {

final void FillList1(){
    try{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=BIS";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "*****";
    Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Students");
    while(res.next()){
        DLM.addElement(res.getString("ID"));
    }
    List1.setModel(DLM);
}
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
    }
}

final void FillList2(){
    try{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=BIS";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "*****";
    Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM FinishedCourses WHERE ID = '"+List1.getSelectedValue()+"'";
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

    ResultSet res1;
    String S_Code;
    String Query1;

    while(res.next()){

         S_Code = res.getString("S_Code");
         Query1 = "SELECT * From Subjects WHERE Prerequisite = '"+S_Code+"'";
         res1 = stmt.executeQuery(Query1);

        while(res1.next()){

            DLM.addElement(res.getString("S_Code"));
        }

    }
    conn.close();
    stmt.close();
    List2.setModel(DLM);
}
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
    }
}

public AddSubToStd() {
    initComponents();
    FillList1();

}
```

but I get the `SQLException` that says the result set is closed when I try to invoke `FillList2()`

```
 private void UpdateAllowedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=BIS";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "*****";
    Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    FillList2();    
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
    }

}
```

someone please help.

Comment: Add a `e.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` and add the stack trace to your question, please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're re-using the same `Statement` object to execute two queries. When the `stmt` is used to execute the second query, the  `ResultSet` object returned by the previous statement is closed. Create two objects for each query.

Example:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
...
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

...

while(res.next()){

     S_Code = res.getString("S_Code");
     Query1 = "SELECT * From Subjects WHERE Prerequisite = '"+S_Code+"'";
     res1 = stmt1.executeQuery(Query1); // use a separate statement

    while(res1.next()){

        DLM.addElement(res.getString("S_Code"));
    }

}
```

This is explained in the following quote from the [`Statement` API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. **All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.**

Also it is strongly recommended to close the JDBC resources in the *reverse order* of their allocation, i.e.g you should close `Statement`s then close the `Connection`, and you should do this in a `finally` block:

```
catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
} finally {
    if(res != null) {
        res.close();
    }
    if(res1 != null) {
        res1.close();
    }
    if(stmt != null) {
        stmt.close();
    }
    if(stmt1 != null) {
        stmt1.close();
    }
    if(conn != null) {
         conn.close();
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 7, you can use a try-with-resources statement to automatically close these resources (without having to explicitly call the `close()` method):

```
// try-with-resources statement declaring two resources
try(Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    ...
} catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
}
```

The try-with-resources will make sure to close the `Statement` object, then the `Connection` after they are used.

Comment: For the last part of your answer, it is better to use try-with-resource: it guarantees closing in the right order, even if exceptions occur (for example if an exception is thrown in your example finally block, then the connection might not get closed).

Comment: It's also advisable to use a `PreparedStatement` so that the OP will not get into trouble with course codes like `'; DROP TABLE Students; --` :)

Comment: Thanks a million guys. the try-with-resources worked perfectly :D

Comment: and btw I have no idea what the PreparedStatement is or how it is used. I am still new to this stuff so i have zero knowledge.

Comment: [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on `PreparedStatement`s gives a good overview. In short, you want to use them every time you pass in variables into your SQL, to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and to enable the DB to re-use your queries.